# Should I use a constructor to create instances of a virtual class for my EF POCO classes?

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following POCO class that I defined and will use with Entity Framework:

```
public class Application
{
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TestAccount> TestAccounts { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the Table that it created with EF Code First

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Application] (
    [ApplicationId] INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]          NVARCHAR (35) NOT NULL,
    [RowVersion]    ROWVERSION    NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ApplicationId] ASC)
);
```

It was suggested to me that I should have a constructor and in that construct
a TestAccounts collection. Is this correct and if so what would be the best 
way to create this.

One more question. For TestAccounts should I use an IList or ICollection? I 
am not sure what the best would be?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have virtual properties, you probably going to use POCO with proxies. In this case you cannot construct correct proxy manually and must always use ObjectSet.CreateObject or DbSet equivalent of this method for new objects instantiation.